# DataSnapshot.getChildrenCount has error "The getter 'getChildrenCount' isn't defined for the type 'DataSnapshot'."

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get a count of how many children are in a path. I could not find anyone else with this problem.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: But since you tagged with Flutter, you are likely looking for `snapshot.children.length`. Also see https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DataSnapshot-class.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getChildrenCount()` method is part of the Android SDK for Firebase Realtime Database. But since you tagged with Flutter, you are likely looking for `snapshot.children.length`. Also see the reference docs for the [DataSnapshot class](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DataSnapshot-class.html).

Comment: DataSnapshot.children.length also has error "The getter 'children' isn't defined for the type 'DataSnapshot'." I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

Comment: Given that it's declared right in the documentation I linked, you're likely on an older version that where the `children` property was introduced. But it's hard to be sure of that without seeing a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem in your question.